# Retrieve JSON data by index

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am using PHP `json_encode()` to generate JSON data of a shopping cart:

```
{
  "6cb380f1bfbcd7728be7dfbf2be6bad4": {
    "rowid": "6cb380f1bfbcd7728be7dfbf2be6bad4",
    "id": "sku_131ABC",
    "qty": "4",
    "price": "35.95",
    "name": "T-Shirt",
    "options": {
      "Size": "M",
      "Color": "Red"
    },
    "subtotal": 143.8
  }
}
```

As you notice the initial ID is unique and not predictable. Is there a way in JavaScript 
where I can use this data? I am trying to get the values of qty, price(etc).

I was thinking if something on the lines of an index reference exists.

```
Thedata[0].name
```

I know this doesn't work, but is something like this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work for you:

```
for (key in Data) {
    alert(Data[key].name);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if you can do it without loop, but something like this should work.

```
for (key in data) {
    alert(data[key].name);
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See json_sans_eval here: http://json.org/

Comment: You could just link directly to http://code.google.com/p/json-sans-eval/ - also, this is of interest - http://www.json.org/js.html - which is all great, but still doesn't directly answer OP's question.